# Weak-* convergence in Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let's consider a sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ in the space $L^\infty(0,T;H^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$.
What does it mean that $\{f_n\}_n$ converges weakly-* in $L^\infty(0,T;H^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not well defined. Weak-* convergence is only defined in dual spaces.

Typically, one means that there is $f \in L^\infty(0,T;H^1)$, such that for all $v \in L^1(0,T;H^1)$ you have
$$\int_0^T (f_n(t)-f(t), v(t))_{H^1} \, \mathrm{d}t \to 0.$$
Here, $(\cdot,\cdot)_{H^1}$ is your favourite scalar product in $H^1$. The reason is that the dual space of $L^1(0,T;H^1)$ can be identified with $L^\infty(0,T;H^1)$.